# multiple model objects saved to db even though view screens out MyModel.DoesNotExist breaking application

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I am getting the following error trying to retrieve a user profile from the mongodb:

```
New searches for user 555555555
[{'search_term': 'ibm'}, {'search_term': 'ry'}]
Internal Server Error: /users/555555555
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cchilders/projects/stocks_backend/users/views.py", line 50, in get_user_profile
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 433, in get
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
users.models.UserProfile.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one UserProfile -- it returned 2!
[21/Aug/2022 09:45:31] "POST /users/555555555 HTTP/1.1" 500 76920
```

Having multiple user profiles is application breaking and there should only be one for each user. I am also getting duplicates in another model StockInfo.

my view appears to only save a new user when none exists for that user id so I'm confused

users/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

import json

from helpers.view_functions import parse_request_body
from .models import UserProfile


@csrf_exempt
def get_user_profile(request, user_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            user = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
            print("user found")
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            print("user does not exist exception")
            profile = UserProfile()
            profile.user_id = user_id
            profile.searches = [
                {'search_term': 'hd'},
                {'search_term': 'wba'},
            ]
            profile.display_settings = [
                {'setting_name': 'showYieldChange', 'visible': True},
                {'setting_name': 'showAllDividends', 'visible': True},
            ]
            profile.save()
            print("user saved in db")
            user = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
        except Exception as error:
            print("got an unknown exception:")
            print(error)

        data = {
            'user_id': user.user_id,
            'searches': user.searches,
            'display_settings': user.display_settings
        }
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        return HttpResponse({json_data}, content_type='application/json')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        body = parse_request_body(request)
        searches = body['searches']
        searches_objects = [{'search_term': x} for x in searches]
        print("New searches for user {user_id}".format(user_id=user_id))
        print(searches_objects)
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
        user.searches = searches_objects
        user.display_settings = body['display_settings']
        user.save()
        return HttpResponse("it worked")
```

in case it matters here's users/models.py:

```
from djongo import models


class RecentSearch(models.Model):
    search_term = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class DisplaySetting(models.Model):
    setting_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    visible = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    searches = models.ArrayField(model_container=RecentSearch, null=True)
    display_settings = models.ArrayField(model_container=DisplaySetting, null=True)

    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

Is `user = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_id)` asynchronous and not returning in time to be checked in the try statement? I wouldn't expect python to have a race condition here since I'm not using any async keywords.

When I change code to use get_or_create it breaks again, getting error that there are more than 1 user profile:

```
def get_user_profile(request, user_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        
        user, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user_id, defaults={
            'user_id': user_id,
            'searches': [
                {'search_term': 'hd'},
                {'search_term': 'wba'},
            ],
            'display_settings': [
                {'setting_name': 'showYieldChange', 'visible': True},
                {'setting_name': 'showAllDividends', 'visible': True},
            ]
        })

        if created:
            print("user saved in db")
       
        data = {
            'user_id': user.user_id,
            'searches': user.searches,
            'display_settings': user.display_settings
        }
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        return HttpResponse({json_data}, content_type='application/json')
```

I tried passing in user_id in the default dict also.

```
New searches for user 114260670592402026255
[{'search_term': 'ibm'}, {'search_term': 'ry'}, {'search_term': 'td'}]
Internal Server Error: /users/114260670592402026255
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cchilders/projects/stocks_backend/users/views.py", line 62, in get_user_profile
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 433, in get
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
users.models.UserProfile.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one UserProfile -- it returned 2!
[21/Aug/2022 16:23:20] "POST /users/114260670592402026255 HTTP/1.1" 500 76995
```

Using transaction.atomic also causes duplicate user profiles:

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_user_profile(request, user_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            user, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user_id, defaults={
                'user_id': user_id,
                'searches': [
                    {'search_term': 'hd'},
                    {'search_term': 'wba'},
                ],
                'display_settings': [
                    {'setting_name': 'showYieldChange', 'visible': True},
                    {'setting_name': 'showAllDividends', 'visible': True},
                ]
            })

        user = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_id)


        data = {
            'user_id': user.user_id,
            'searches': user.searches,
            'display_settings': user.display_settings
        }
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        return HttpResponse({json_data}, content_type='application/json')
```

I need this view to never save a duplicate user profile once the first one is made

Comment: Use get_or_create from django itself. Works wonders. Can I ask why the userprofile isn't a OneToOnefield to user? Would make a lot of this lots easier for you (From what I can see here).

Comment: so I used get or create and check the created flag, and if created is true then I add the attributes and save

Comment: let me run some manual tests

Comment: i dropped the database and it's still making duplicates, let me drop it again

Comment: I deleted the whole database and restarted app and still getting duplicates. could you show a code sample using transaction.atomic() please

Comment: ok I tried transaction.atomic and still making duplicates

Comment: does the signals solution work?

Answer (score 0):

In your django APPLICATION (not project)

- create a file called `signals.py`
- Go to the "apps.py" file, and add the following `ready()` method to the class.

```
class MyApplicationConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'myapplication'

    def ready(self):
        import myapplication.signals
```

^^^ The class itself is just an example, the ready method is self explanatory

- Then we will get to creating a signal -> go into signals.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from myapplication.models import Userprofile
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# ^ Nescessary imports to create a signal to be sent after User creation.

@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def create_profile_signal(
        sender, # The User class specified above
        instance, # The actual user instance that was edited
        created, # self explanatory
        **kwargs # Nescessary kwargs.
    ):
    if created: # Assign the current user's instance to the userprofile to create one.
        profile = UserProfile.objects.create()
        profile.user_id = instance.id # -> profile.user = instance if you have a OneToOneField named user.
        profile.searches = [
            {'search_term': 'hd'},
            {'search_term': 'wba'},
        ]
        profile.display_settings = [
            {'setting_name': 'showYieldChange', 'visible': True},
            {'setting_name': 'showAllDividends', 'visible': True},
        ]
        profile.save()
```

- Then, you need to fully restart your django project (Stop and start the built-in runserver), django is not good at picking up on newly created files.

So what now?
Every time a user signs up to your django project, the userprofile will automatically be created. You do not need to do this yourself. No hassle in views and such. You can ofcourse, also set defaults like before.

##### Some extra information:

> Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework

There are a lot of signals, it's nice to look into. Examples are pre_save, post_save, post_delete, m2m_changed

- Most of them take different arguments.
- Whenever a model gets saved, a signal gets sent.
- So when the user signs up, a signal gets sent.
- In post_save, we can specify the created argument, we use this to check if the user that was saved was created
- We have created a function to 'capture' that signal.
- In that function we can apply logic to the instance. Please, do not call `.save()` on the instance in signals. Unless it's in the `if created:` login, it will create a loop and error.
- If you seek to edit a model instance in signals, use pre_save, and don't save the instance afterwards.

What else do I need to do in the view?

- You basically don't have to do anything if  you implemented the signal. Whenever a user signs up, the profile will get created automatically.

What do I need to do in the model?

- You dont /HAVE/ to do anything with the model,

Optional:

- but I think this field on the userprofile will help you out a lot:  `user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)`

Comment: It's been a while since I did django I forgot about the User model. Last time I did login I did a user model with a one to one to my user profile model

Comment: Do you want me to edit the signal to include a model, instead of just the id? You'll have to edit models.py yourself. @codyc4321

Comment: sure. I'm still confused what to do in the view and model, how does the signal know to run? what triggers it

Comment: @codyc4321 check my edit.

Comment: what you mean user signs up? Do I keep my view the same

Comment: Nope, you can throw the view away basically. All logic creating the userprofile has been automatically moved to Django's signals framework. Now if you call `User.objects.create_user()`, it will automatically have a userprofile associated with it after saving the model. @codyc4321

Comment: this won't work yet since im not using the User model just the UserProfile model I created. Do I need to first implement User and extend it with user profile? Also I'm using mongodb Djongo not relational db. How would the app know a user was signing up if I don't sign them up in the view?

Comment: I'm only using Google Auth to sign up, the code can be found at https://github.com/codyc4321/dividends_ui front end and https://github.com/codyc4321/stocks_backend for the backend

Comment: If we can get it working I can tip you on cash app

Comment: After a models `.save()` method gets called, django doesn't straight send it to the database. It does some other stuff first, which includes broadcasting this information cross-app. If you want, you can add `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`, and specify `models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), ...)`. I'll edit my code to account for custom user model.

Comment: @codyc4321, 1. I dont have a cashapp, 2. I don't need money. We're on stackoverflow, not fiverr. Appreciate it though. I am however not too familiar with google auth. The only thing this signal is missing, is the user model. I'll look at the app, see what I can figure out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247431/discussion-between-nigel239-and-codyc4321).